# Java - Clipboard copied content disappear after program exits

Tags: java

I would like to replace the system clipboard content with my java code, 
but the copied content disappears once the java program exits. How can I make the data persistent?

Thanks a lot.

```
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        Transferable t = clipboard.getContents(null);

        if (t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
        {
            String data = (String) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            System.out.println(data);
        }

        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("Replaced Text");
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);

        // just to keep program running... 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.nextLine();
```

edit: I work on Ubuntu 10.10, with java version 1.6_20.

Comment: I just noticed that this is not just a java specific problem. clipboard content I copy in firefox also disappears when I close it.

Comment: hmm, maybe it is a platform specific situation. what operating system are you using?

Comment: It persists in Windows 7 not in Ubuntu 10.10 (just checked)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the one that (your program) put the clipboard content on the clipboard must be able to serv it in Ubuntu 10.10.

Installing [glipper](http://glipper.sourceforge.net/) (`sudo apt-get install glipper`) works for me. It manages your clipboard. (It's an applet so it seems that it must be added to your panel to start.)

Comment: I was going to try Clipboard deamon (http://members.chello.nl/~h.lai/gnome-clipboard-daemon/).