# Getting Clipboard Access in an Applet for Ubuntu Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, ubuntu, applet, clipboard

I'm running a 64-bit Ubuntu with an applet in Firefox.  When the applet attempts to read the clipboard.  I get this error:

`Error: uncaught exception: LiveConnectPermissionNeeded access denied (java.awt.AWTPermission accessClipboard)`

I would like to enable clipboard access for this particular applet.  Any idea how?  I'm running the IcedTea plugin.  This works fine with IE in Windows (using JDK6 plugin).

I tried installing the Oracle Java 6 plugin:
`sudo apt-get install sun-java6-plugin`

It didn't seem to have any usable files and did not give any errors or warnings during the install.

I'm open to any ideas on how to get this to work.

Comment: Could it be that you are accessing your applet from JavaScript here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you asked.  See the thread [Copy in sand-boxed app. in 1.6.0_24+](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2197433) over at the OTN for a potential solution.

In fact, I'd appreciate your test results for that code I posted - details in the thread.  I got it moved from the Swing forum to the Java Programming forum to try & get some results for any OS besides Windows, but have so far got no non-Windows results.

If you paste the data & comments here, I'll include it in the [Results table](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2197433#results) & link back.

Comment: I just tried your applet ... but in fact I have only 1.6.0_20 here (on OpenSUSE with IcedTea), and there is no button in the applet. It says `java.vendorjava.version 1.6.0_20 java.vendor Sun Microsystems Inc. os.name Linux2.6.34.7-0.7-desktop os.version 2.6.34.7-0.7-desktop` in the text I copy from the applet (without any security warning). Copying to the applet does not really work (it still pastes the last thing I copied in the applet itself). I'll have to try this later on my Ubuntu system (which is hopefully a bit more current).

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann Thanks for your report.  Was that using FF?  Note that 'paste' into the applet is not a design feature, so I neither coded for it nor even thought about it.  Odd though, I thought the default result in a JTable would be to allow pasting data.

Comment: This was in Firefox, yes. In Opera it looks the same, but Ctrl-A does not do anything, I have to mark the cells with the shift+cursor keys. Copying the whole table does not work either (but I can copy the contents of individual cells after starting to edit them). Pasting does not work, too.

Comment: And in fact, in Firefox marking the whole table and copying it only puts it into some Java-intern clipboard, so I can paste it then into one of the cells there. From there I can copy it to the system clipboard with Ctrl-C. Strange.

Comment: In both cases it prints `jnlp.grab.focus=true` on stdout, and does not grab the focus.

Comment: Most disconcerting. :(  I'll have to mull over your results more.

Comment: @Paŭlo  Apparently the plug-in2 is not enabled for those browsers (hence no button).  It seems from your results that I have again presumed a behavior that simply does not exist in that JRE, namely 'Ctrl-c copy' (at least, not in any simple form like copying the entire table data).

Comment: As said, this is the IcedTea plugin, not the Sun one (I'll test the Sun plugin later on another computer and report for you). And copying the whole table works, but only in Firefox and inside the applet, it seems.

Comment: So, here the results for the Sun plugin on Ubuntu, Firefox: Ctrl-A works, Ctrl-C gives a dialog, and after confirmation it puts `java.version 1.6.0_24 
java.vendor Sun Microsystems Inc. 
os.name Linux 
os.version 2.6.35-28-generic ` in the clipboard (including line-breaks and tabs).

Comment: On Opera, Ctrl-A does not work (is captured by the browser, it seems), neither Ctrl-C. Pressing the button gives the confirmation dialog, and then I can paste here `java.version 1.6.0_24 
java.vendor Sun Microsystems Inc. 
os.name Linux 
os.version 2.6.35-28-generic 
`

Comment: In Epiphany, the applet gets the focus. Ctrl-A does not work (it marks the text in the browser instead), Ctrl-C then copies this text (or nothing). Using the button gives us the confirmation dialog, and then `java.version 1.6.0_24 
java.vendor Sun Microsystems Inc. 
os.name Linux 
os.version 2.6.35-28-generic 
`

Comment: In Chromium, Ctrl-A does work if the table already has the focus. Ctrl-C does nothing, the Button gives us the known dialog and then `java.version 1.6.0_24 
java.vendor Sun Microsystems Inc. 
os.name Linux 
os.version 2.6.35-28-generic 
`

Comment: Konqueror redirects me to http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp?host=java.com&returnPage=http://pscode.org/prop/js.html?prop=java.version%2Cjava.vendor%2Cos.name%2Cos.version&jnlp.grab.focus=true&locale=en_GB. Java is activated, but Konqueror uses its own applet environment instead of the plugin, which the launching script does not recognize.

Comment: rekonq does not show the applet at all (only a big white space). It gives a segmentation fault if I try with our applet, so I'll first try to analyze this. (With the Sun VM, still.)

Comment: Now changing to OpenJDK/IcedTea. Rekonq still does not show anything (but my applet works now, only without SSL because of Ubuntu-specific [bug #710273](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+bug/710273))

Comment: Konqueror reacts the same as before.

Comment: Epiphany: No focus grab, Ctrl-A selects the text in the browser. No "Copy" button there, Ctrl-C has no effect (even not from one table cell to the next) - but if something is selected in the browser, this is copied instead.  (It shows 1.6.0_20 here, too.)

Comment: Firefox: No focus grab, but when the table has the focus, Ctrl-A works. Ctrl-C on the table copies only Java-internal, which we can insert in a table cell - but copying outside does not work. With a middle click I can still insert it here: `java.version 1.6.0_20 java.vendor Sun Microsystems Inc. os.name Linux os.version 2.6.35-28-generic`. So it looks like at least manual marking in a JTextField helps to copy it into the "Selection" clipboard here.

Comment: This same "mark in JTextField" => paste with middle click does also work in Epiphany, without even trying to copy. It also works in Suns Plugin in Opera.

Comment: Seems like Opera does not care about the default Java plugin of the system, and has its own setting ... it finds both the IcedTea plugin and the Sun plugin (IcedTea is listed first), and somehow decides to use the Sun plugin. So, no test with IcedTea and Opera on Ubuntu, now. (I suppose it will work similarly like on the OpenSUSE system I tested yesterday.)

Comment: I found one more browser, Seamonkey. It works like the Firefox I described before. `java.version 1.6.0_20 java.vendor Sun Microsystems Inc. os.name Linux os.version 2.6.35-28-generic`.

Comment: Here the versions of the programs in Ubuntu: Seamonkey 2.0.11, Epiphany 2.30.3, Opera 11.01, Firefox 3.6.16, Konqueror 4.5.1, Rekonq 0.6.1.

Comment: Based on your results, I have decided this technique is a failure.  The code is now updated to use JS as a 3rd level of fall-back for presenting data in a way that can be copied.

Comment: xUbuntu: 10.04.2/Firefox 3.6.17: `java.version=1.6.0_24, java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc., os.name=Linux, os.version=2.6.32-32-generic.`

Comment: Btw.: Cut'n'paste fails in the appletviewer (same java version as above) too. I can't insert something from the clipboard into an JApplet in the appletviewer, running on my local machine. I thought my local machine is considered secure?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need this to run in the sandbox or if its a problem to sign your applet, But the permission error is most likely due to your clipboard access not being wrapped in a privileged block. Here is an example of wrapping it. Applet needs to be signed as well.

```
 Clipboard systemClipboard = (Clipboard) AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
        public Object run() 
        {
            Clipboard tempClipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
         return tempClipboard;
        }
    });

    // get the contents on the clipboard in a 
    // Transferable object
    Transferable clipboardContents = systemClipboard.getContents(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't answer the questions, here just one more tip:

To change to the Sun plugin after installing, you have to do `sudo update-java-alternatives java-6-sun`, and then restart Firefox (or at least close and reopen any tabs containing Java applets).

Note: This changes not only the Plugin, but your default JVM for the whole system. If you only want to change the plugin, add the `--plugin` switch (before `java-6-sun`).

But please report whether using the Sun plugin gives you any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the information in this thread helpful.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/42122/cant-copy-from-clipboard-to-any-java-applet

It appears that by default the java.awt library doesn't have access to the system clipboard.

Edit:
The above solution was ultimately unhelpful in my case. I was able to access items in the system clipboard I had placed in java applications by following the advice to download Glipper mentioned in the thread below.

[Java - Clipboard copied content disappear after program exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216756/java-clipboard-copied-content-disappear-after-program-exits)